# Magento 2: Call to a member function getEntityType() on null

Tags: magento2, eav

I'm trying to create a new Eav Entity after [this instruction post](http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-creating-new-eav-entity-and-model). 
Then i got this issue:

> Call to a member function getEntityType() on null

I'm still new with Eav Entity, so can some one help me to figure out what the problem is?

Here is my custom module after follow the instruction: [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CqqsDun6Eu0qB337ocXPer9JDrXunGB-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `Aht/Custom/Model/ResourceModel/Department.php`, `Aht/Custom/Model/ResourceModel/Employee.php` `Aht/Custom/Setup/InstallSchema.php` with content inside this files: https://gist.github.com/rendyep/496a94777662f9729b9422a842b6e415

Get into your mysql client console and do cleanup of some tables created while you failed executing upgrade:

```
mysql> drop table department;
mysql> drop table employee;
mysql> drop table employee_entity;
mysql> drop table employee_entity_datetime;
mysql> drop table employee_entity_decimal;
mysql> drop table employee_entity_int;
mysql> drop table employee_entity_text;
mysql> drop table employee_entity_varchar;
mysql> delete from setup_module where module = 'Aht_Custom';
```

Do upgrade again:

```
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, i will check and tell you the result as soon as i can. By the way, can you tell me what i did wrong in the custom module please? I just wanna learn from it. Thanks again.

Comment: I fixed table naming in resource model and install schema,  and refactor your code, for example, `public function __construct()` which should be `protected function _construct()` in employee resource model.

Comment: Thanks, i've tested and it work perfectly.